# perl out of memory error

Tags: linux, perl, solaris

I have a perl script that spawns 60 child process.  I get an "out of memory error" and no other additional error message to know the cause of it. what does it denote?  Is it because i have 60 child process running in the system simultaneous i get a out of memory error. I dont have big array or hash maps in the process so there should not be memory issue. The child Process just greps the file. 
Solaris 10 is the OS.

1. What is the maximum limit of child process that i can fork in
   Solaris 10?
2. What does out of memory denotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some systems have a 64 child limit. I guess you found one. Reap the ones that have completed to spawn more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I have waitpid function in the main script that waits for the 60 childs to complete. Once all the child process completes the main script quits. I am unable to find any documentation about the maximum child limit. Do you know any weblinks that says 64 is the max limit? Also is the 64 limit can be changed for the individual Unix user or is it common for all the users? Also how can i find a memory used by each child process and memory allocated when a child process is started.

Comment: I've simply heard of the existence of it before. That's all I know. I don't remember it being adjustable, though. `ulimit` controls similar limits, so I'd look there.

Comment: Reduced the child process to 30. Still i get out of memory error. Have a hashmap of 400 keys which are file names mapped to open file handles. This hashmap is a global variable. Using this hashmap in all the child process created to look for a filename and grep the file.  Finally when all the chid process is completed will read the hashmap and close the file handle.  Is this causing any outofmemory issues.  Can this hashmap with open file handles used across all the child process for grepping?

Comment: If its not a good way what is the best way of doing it.  I need a hash map because i am using perl grep. Reading 100000 line from a input file in a child process and grepping across 1000 different files. Thought having hashmap of open file handles will be efficient

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 60 process forks is just too much for any system.
Are you absolutely sure you need all of them? Despite `fork()` being often used as a synonym of *parallelization*, it should be used with care.
For instance, most of the "slow tasks" are I/O bound and can be parallelized via non-blocking asynchronous calls (see [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/Coro) and [Coro](https://metacpan.org/module/Coro)).
Even the CPU bound tasks are tricky: don't expect 60x speed increase with 60 subprocesses unless you have a 64-core [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_Multiprocessor) machine.
Also, here is a nice comparison chart for Perl concurrent programming: http://blog.64p.org/entries/2009/06/30

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library such as [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) to keep the number of simultaneous processes down to some limit.